# WPF: Using binding in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm using a two column (ID,NAME) DataGrid and want update the row with new values.

I'm not sure how I can use the binding part in my C# code.

```
 <DataGrid Name="dataGridUser" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

How can I update the datagrid with net values like :

ID , Name
123, Peter
345, Simon
....

Comment: `ItemsSource` should have a binding like `{Binding MyItems}` where `MyItems` would be an `ObservableCollection` and you would have it as a public property in whatever data source you have active.

Answer (score 1):

So to give you an Example, first create a Model

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then in your Code-Behind File create an ObservableCollection of that Model

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _myUsers;

    public ObservableCollection<User> MyUsers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myUsers == null)
            {
                _myUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            }
            return _myUsers;
        }
    }
```

and now you can bind your DataGrid to this Property

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dataGridUser" ItemsSource="{Binding MyUsers}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

and don´t forget to set the DataContext

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Window>
```

if you add a new User to the ObservableCollection MyUsers it will immediately be displayed in your DataGrid, but if you change the FirstName of a existing User it will not display the changes. To do this you must implement [INotityPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) in your Model.

But if you plan to develop a more complex Application I would recommend to take a look at the MVVM-Pattern.

Personally I like the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) this [Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/kreekman/techdays-2010-understanding-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern) should give you a good Idea what MVVM is all about.